# Output the repeat rule for an event

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Is it possible to output the repeat rules for recurring events with Solspace Calendar?

For example, instead of listing all of the occurrences, output something like "Repeats Daily", "Every Monday and Friday", etc.

Or should I just add an extra text field where the author can enter their own description of the schedule?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to do this, but might be in a future version of Calendar. :)